# Simple Membership Provider not working after its published

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with my simply membership provider.

I have my local VS2013 machine with with a remote sqlserver.

When i run the website locally it works and i can create users, and login.

When i publish the site simply refuses to create the user and returns you to the signup page.
The SQL Server and the published website reside on the same server.

All other requests to the server works (content for the website)

The code for the register method is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

the web.comfig:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=this.is.my.host.name;initial catalog=DBNAME;persist security info=True;user id=thisismyuser;password=thisismypassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It seems the modelstate or the result contains nothing.

Anyone have a clue about this?

I have to mention that it has worked before on the published site before. For whatever reasion it doesnt anymore.

I have even tried to delete the tables associated with the simple membership provider. - When i do this they get recreated when i run it from VS2013, but they dont when i run it from the published server.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Would you able to check the event log and see any errors during the request. Then may be try to run a sql profiler to see whether the queries being executed?

Comment: Hello Raj. I tried using sql profiler, and it seems all user related never reaches the sql server. Something must go wrong with the calls. I tripple checked the username and passwords. I tried looking at the event log, but cannot find any logs pertaining to the web server. Where would i find these logfiles? As a note: All ENtity Framework calls reaches the SQL server, everything related to the membership provider seems to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

It was pretty unrelated. The error was related to the rewrite module that messed up my login on the server, but not locally.

After removing the related rules, everything worked as expected!

Thank you for your help Raj.